# Find the Laurent Series Representation of the Function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

$ f(z)=\frac{2z+1}{(z-1)(z+3) } $

Around,  $ z=0$

Inside the annulus defined by  $ 1< \left | z \right |< 3$

This is what I get: $ \frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{z^n})+\frac{4}{15}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{3})^n(z^n) $

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

I get another factor in front of the second series:
$$
\frac{2z+1}{(z-1)(z+3)}
= \frac{3/4}{z-1} + \frac{5/4}{z+3}
= \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac1z} + \frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac z3} \\
= \frac34 \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac1z\right)^n + \frac{5}{12} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac z3\right)^n \\
= \frac34 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac1z\right)^n + \frac{5}{12} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac z3\right)^n \\
$$

Comment: true, I mistakenly flipped the 5/4. Is there any way two simplify or join the two final series?

Comment: No, it's easiest to keep them apart. One has negative powers of $z$ and the other has non-negative powers of $z$.

Comment: How go about in the infinite annulus defined by modulus of zet greater than 3?

Comment: Fir $|z|>3$ we use
$$
\frac{1}{z+3} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1+3/z} = \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{3}{z}\right)^n.
$$

Comment: Thank you! For  |z|>3, I get $$\sum_{1}^{\infty }(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{4}(-3)^{(n-1)})(\frac{1}{z^{n}})$$